# How to command if ( ..) don't executive setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery

This [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/58PKb/1/),
After landing page it will show `btn2`(green area), then user have 2 option:

1. user do nothing - `setTimeout()`
2. user hover to `btn2`-  show `btn3`(blue).  
I stuck in 2. after hover to `btn2` and `btn3` be show. `btn1`(red) still fadeIn how to cancel it?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
<div class="btn btn1"></div>
<div class="btn btn2"></div>
<div class="btn btn3"></div>
.btn{
width: 200px;
position: absolute;
}
.btn1{
background-color: red;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
.btn2{
background-color: green;
height: 200px;
opacity: 0.3;
display: none;
}
.btn3{
background-color: blue;
height: 200px;
opacity: 0.3;
display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
function navctr(){
    //landing
    $('.btn1').hide();
    $('.btn2').show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.btn2').fadeOut(50);
        $('.btn1').fadeIn(50);
    }, 2250);
    //after click
    $('.btn1').click(function(){
        $('.btn1').fadeOut(100);
        $('.btn2').delay(100).fadeIn(50);
    });
    //both
    $('.btn2').hover(function(){
        $('.btn2').hide();
        $('.btn3').fadeIn(100);
    });
    $('.btn3').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.btn3').fadeOut(50);
        $('.btn1').fadeIn(100);
    });
};
navctr();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method `clearTimeout()` : [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout) it will remove a timeout previously set on your document.

With your code it would be something like this :

```
$(function(){
function navctr(){
    var myTimeout;
    //landing
    $('.btn1').hide();
    $('.btn2').show();
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.btn2').fadeOut(50);
        $('.btn1').fadeIn(50);
    }, 2250);
    //after click
    $('.btn1').click(function(){
        $('.btn1').fadeOut(100);
        $('.btn2').delay(100).fadeIn(50);
    });
    //both
    $('.btn2').hover(function(){
        $('.btn2').hide();
        $('.btn3').fadeIn(100);
        clearTimeout(myTimeout); // remove the setTimeout
    });
    $('.btn3').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.btn3').fadeOut(50);
        $('.btn1').fadeIn(100);
    });
};
navctr();
});
```